# Downloading files from imanage/worksite/filesite

Tags: vba, excel, imanage

I got this problem at work that I have to do a lot with iManage (aka FileSite, DeskSite, WorkSite etc.) and maybe you've heard of it.

Anyways, what I'm trying to do is to write a VBA code which will be able to download a particular file based on its `InFin` number (7-digit number that is assigned to every file when being uploaded to iManage) and then place the file somewhere; For example, on the Desktop.
I know that iManage does expose an object model and I've already set the reference to `IManExtLib.dll`

I believe that the command I need is the `Copy.Cmd` (I don't want to cut sth from WorkSite but only download a copy of the file for the performed task).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your question? Please read> [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you already have a DMS session, you need to get an IManDocument object for your document you're trying to get and then call the GetCopy method. As an example, the following retrieves a physical copy of document number 123456 to a temp folder. Note you'll need to add a reference to IManage.dll as opposed to IManExtLib.dll.

```
Dim dmsRoot As IManDMS
Dim dmsSession As IManSession
Dim dmsDatabase As IManDatabase
Dim doc As IManDocument

Dim tempDocName As String

Const ServerName As String = "YourDMS"
Const DatabaseName As String = "YourDatabaseName"
Const DocNumToFind = 123456
Const DocVerToFind = 1

    tempDocName = "C:\temp\mydoc.doc"

    Set dmsRoot = New ManDMS
    Set dmsSession = dmsRoot.Sessions.Add(ServerName)
    dmsSession.TrustedLogin

    Set dmsDatabase = dmsSession.Databases.ItemByName(DatabaseName)

    Set doc = dmsDatabase.GetDocument(DocNumToFind, DocVerToFind)
    doc.GetCopy tempDocName, imGetCopyOptions.imNativeFormat
```

Comment: Hey. The code works. Thank you so much. Can I only ask if there's a possibility for the code to recognise the format of the file stored on Worksite (.xlsx, .pdf or .doc) and download it in that format?

Comment: The .Extension property on the IManDocument object should contain the original extension of the file.